# How to modify the function of an object in java script

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I have following code where I want to modify info function.

```js
function Car(type) {
  this.info = function() {
    console.log("this is a ", type, " car");
  };
}
let obj = new Car("BMW");
obj.info();
```

Comment: *How to modify the function of an object in java script* What exactly do you mean by this? You should be specify how do you want to modify, what part of a function do you want to modify? What should be the expected result in this case?

Comment: Just put different code in that function in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Simply overwrite the function:

```js
function Car(type) {
  this.info = function() {
    console.log("this is a ", type, " car");
  };
}

let obj = new Car("BMW");
obj.info();

// Overwrite info()
obj.info = function() {
  console.log("New function");
}
obj.info();
```